# Favicon probably stuck due to .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, favicon

I've made a custom .htaccess file in order to work with 'clean urls' on my website, but now my favicon has stopped working. I guess that's because of my rewrite rules, but i am not sure.
The favicon is placed in the root as /favicon.ico and is called for in the header of my site. 
This is the htaccess I use:

```
#rewite part
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{http_host} ^theroyalinstitute.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.theroyalinstitute.com/$1 [L,R=301] 

AddType image/x-icon .ico 
AddType text/xml .xml
AddType application/x-woff .woff

#Etags
Header unset Pragma 
Header unset ETag
FileETag none

#Expires-header regelt de caching in de browser.
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On

    ExpiresByType text/html A0

    ExpiresByType text/xml A60


    #One month
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon A604800

    ExpiresByType image/gif A604800
    ExpiresByType image/png A604800
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg A604800

    ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash A604800

    ExpiresByType application/x-woff A2592000
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript A2592000
    ExpiresByType text/css A2592000

</IfModule>

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/?$ index.php [L]

# compress all js & css:
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/css text/plain text/xml application/x-javascript application/x-woff application/json
Header append Vary Accept-Encoding
```

Who has the answer, tip or solution?

Comment: You would of considered forwarding www.example.com to example.com. I find the often superfluous prefix annoying. :P

Comment: Can you browse directly to the favico in a browser? eg www.example.com/favico.ico For me, the following comes back as Forbidden: http://www.theroyalinstitute.com/favicon.ico

Comment: @Andrew M: No, I cannot browse directly to it, i get a 403 Forbidden too... Don't really know how to solve...

Comment: @Bart, OK, I think it might be permissions on that file, not rewriting (but I'm not an apache expert). The fact that http://theroyalinstitute.com/favicon.ico redirects to http://www.theroyalinstitute.com/favicon.ico but the throws a Forbidden, suggests the rewrite is working fine, but the file itself cannot be served for some reason.

Comment: OK, WRT Those two links in my last comment, non-www gets redirected to www, but then is forbidden after the redirect. (SO turned my urls into links, but removed the prefixes)

Comment: @Andrew M: Strange thing, I changed the permissions on the file and it worked instantly. How strange that the permission was wrong initially. Thanks anyway, such a simple solution!

Answer (score 2):

Try changing this line:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
```

to this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/favicon\.ico$
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all your comments, apparently the problem was in the CHMOD permissions instead of the whole rewrite part!